# Django ORM filter function

Tags: django

Is there a way to use an expression in django filter function like a key.

I am trying to do this:

```
models.Product.objects.filter("name_cn" = "smth")
```

and get an error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `name_cn` is a variable, then put it in a dictionary, and [deliver the keyword arguments in your dictionary using the `**` operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
models.Product.objects.filter(**{name_cn: "smth"})
```

If `"name_cn"` is the name of the field you want to filter on, then try:

```
models.Product.objects.filter(name_cn="smth")
```

Comment: if "name_cn" is known when he's writing the code, what he probably wants is `models.Product.objects.filter(name_cn = "smth")`